# T-Sql insert nvarchar to varbinary, different value after the insert

Tags: sql, t-sql, insert, type-conversion

I want insert to table [file] image. File_bytes is varbinary, script below works, but after the insert I see in db different value, not "0x89504E470D0A..." but "0x30007800380039..."

Why?

```
insert into [file](PHYSICAL_FILE_NAME, file_bytes, size, insert_Date, DESCRIPTION, version, IS_BLOCKED) 
select 'File.png', CONVERT(varbinary(max), 
-- start convert
convert(nvarchar(max), 
'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more and more :))'
,1)), 
-- end convert
9097295, getutcdate(), 'File.png', 1.0, 1
```

Comment: What is the nvarchar cast there for?  To convert the hex *string* just use `CONVERT(varbinary(max), '0x89...', 1)` or just insert `0x89...` directly as a varbinary literal by removing the single quotes.

Comment: I can't `Error converting data type varchar to varbinary.` 
When i using:
 `CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), 0x89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D494844520...', 1)`

Comment: The length of the string is likely odd, meaning its incomplete.

Comment: hmm length of my hex is odd, it's a .png file, and when i convert hex to file still works fine... how can I insert this hex to db? i try add 0 to the beginning, but file doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to adjuct my hex?

Comment: 0x3000780038003900 is the binary represenation of the nvarchar string "0x89", like this: 3000 is "0", 7800 is "x", 3800 is "8", 3900 is "9".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
insert into [file](PHYSICAL_FILE_NAME, file_bytes, size, insert_Date, DESCRIPTION, version, IS_BLOCKED) 
select 'File.png', CONVERT(varbinary(max), 
0x89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484452000007830000049E0806000000--... and more ...
), 
9097295, getutcdate(), 'File.png', 1.0, 1
```

Comment: My problem is hex, the application saves it to the database (everything works fine), but when i try copy it from the database to create the insert query, hex have an odd number of characters, perhaps because it is a debt and I can not copy it all?

Comment: If you display the results in SQL Server Management Studio, it truncates the results. See (or change) the setting in Tools / Options / Query Results / SQL Server: Results to Grid / Maximum characters retrieved and Results to Text / Maximum number of characters displayed in each column.

Comment: I generated the hex from the application level, unfortunately it's so long that when I copied it to sql management stutio it hangs.